# Converting a UIViewController to a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

There is a class that's a fully fledged UIViewController and when that page loads it works very nice.

I want to change how it works and rather than push on a new ViewController form my current viewcontroller, I'd rather just show this UIViewController inside a UIView on the current screen that usually launchs the new UIViewController.

This is hard to explain.

UIVC_A pushes UIVC_B onto the NavController.

Instead of having UIVC_B getting pushed onto the NavController.

I'd rather creat a UIView in UIVC_A and have UIVC_B appear inside this as a subview of UIVC_A.

What would I need to do/change to get this kind of thing working.

I tried

```
CVC *cv = [[CVC alloc] init];    
UIView * aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 600, 600)];
aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[aView addSubview:cv.view];
[self.view addSubview:aView];
```

But it did not work.

CVC is a UIViewController.

Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't work because the CVC's xib file hasn't unarchived yet. It's view hierarchy is available for usage after it has been loaded (the callback is -viewDidLoad).

What you need to do is programmatically load nib and use it's contents:

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CVC" owner:nil options:nil]; // will return the whole view tree with the CVC's view as it's 0 object
UIView *cvcView = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

and proceed as you did with the view.

Answer (score 1):

Add this function to your CVC view controller

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
```

and try with this code

```
CVC *cv = [[CVC alloc] initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];    
UIView * aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 600, 600)];
aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[aView addSubview:cv.view];
[self.view addSubview:aView];
```

this code is working fine for me I think you too, good luck!!!.